# Linked Server Using a DNS Alias Returning Bad Data

Tags: sql-server-2017, linked-server, dns

Somehow on the same DEV server we have two Linked Servers to the same PROD server. While that, in and of itself, is not an issue; we have noted something we can't explain and we wonder of anyone else has experienced something similar.
One of the Linked Servers is named using the actual machine name (ProductionSQLServerData) and the second is named using the DNS alias (ProdData) for that machine.
In a command window from any machine both names ping to the same IP address. We have checked the source and the target machines and there are no entries in the host files that would misdirect the queries.
We are stumped and wonder ir anyone else has experienced this type of behavior and was able to track down the reason for it. Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: By "returning bad data" it seems you suspect data are returned from different servers. Run `EXECUTE (N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME;') AT ProductionSQLServerData;` and again with ProdData to verify the servers are indeed different. If different, script the linked server definition to verify the connection properties are expected.

Comment: To add on to what Dan said, if they are truly the same server it's possible they are connecting via different accounts which have different privileges and would explain why they return different data, especially if **Row-Level Security** is being used. Verify the accounts used to connect to each **linked server** instance is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Dan and J.D. The EXECUTE statement returns the same @@ServerName in each case. The Linked Servers are, if fact using different Service Accounts as J.D. suggests. However, the permissions for these accounts are identical for the table that is being queried. As I review this I realized that I should have been more specific about the difference in the results sets. The query being run is an aggregate query using the syntax SELECT MAX(FYear), COUNT(*) FROM [Alias Machine] and the same query FROM [Prod Machine]. The alias returns 2020, 120. Prod is 2021, 1100.

Comment: For a sanity check - on the production server, can you use [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for _each_ of the logins that are being used by the linked server connections and run the same query.  I'm just trying to remove the linked server from the equation.